# How to make ImageView fullscreen programmatically on click?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is what I'm trying to do. I have 4 images and they are in one `LinearLayout` and that `LinearLayout` is child of `RelativeLayout`. I have successfully implemented `onClickListener`. Maybe my question is a little different, but everything is relevant.

I don't know how to extend image to full screen because images are in one `LinearLayout` which is inside that one `RelativeLayout` and maybe everything will be clear when I show you guys xml code.

I would like to make `ImageView` full screen on click and to be able to go back when I click back button. For that I would probably need to use `onBackPressed`

Images are at the bottom.

**So here is the xml code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/url"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <RelativeLayout                   
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <!-- Thumbnail Image -->

            <com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />

            <!-- Naslov Filma -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textColor="#7F0000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_movie"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail" >

            </TextView>
            <!-- Godina izdanja Filma -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_red" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rating_star"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_actions_rating_icon" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/url_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                style="@style/UrlDugme" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rating_star"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rating_star"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rating_star"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rating_star"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_red"
                android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

            <!-- Opis Filma -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_round_rect_shape" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_red"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <!-- Opis Filma Zavrsetak -->


            <!-- Glumci -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_round_rect_shape"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutActors"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Image1"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />

                    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Image2"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />

                    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Image3"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutActors"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ime1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Ime"
                        android:textColor="#7F0000"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ime2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Ime"
                        android:textColor="#7F0000"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ime3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Ime"
                        android:textColor="#7F0000"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <!-- Glumci -->

                    <!-- IMAGES I WANT TO MAKE FULLSCREEN ON CLICK -->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/layout_round_rect_shape"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutImages"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image1"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="115dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" >
                            </com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView>    

                            <com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image2"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="115dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" >
                            </com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView>

                            <com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image3"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="115dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" >
                           </com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView>     

                            <com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image4"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="115dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" >
                            </com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView>                                                    

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!-- IMAGES I WANT TO MAKE FULLSCREEN ON CLICK -->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>       

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And here is onClickListener:**

```
image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 115, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int px1 = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 150, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.
                    LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            p.weight = 1;
            if(isImageFitToScreen) {
                image1.setMinimumWidth(px);
                image1.setMinimumHeight(px1);
                image1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                isImageFitToScreen=false;
            }else{
                image1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                image1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                isImageFitToScreen=true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: How about creating an `ImageView` inside you root layout without background (or with `gone` visibility). Then on a click you can load your image into that, and remove it gain on back pressed. May be simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow Dusan,

I've something very similar, but all I do is just put the full screen image in a new activity & pass the image as bytes & display it in a full screened imageview. As soon as they press back, they're returned to where they were before. I think trying to change the layout parameters is a bit overkill here.

Comment: I will try that. Could you give me some example, because i'm new in this and need some help.

Comment: Passing image as bytes and receiving in second activity.

Comment: No, i'm passing those images from Json and i will try to be more undestandable to make you a better view what i have. I have ListView and populiting that listView from Json. I have set those 4 images gone in that ListView and pass them as String to this activity where i want them to be visible, but now i want to make them fullscreen on click.

Comment: Yes, they are from internet and i'm using Universal Loading Image library to load them from there. Here is the method for loading images. `imageLoader.displayImage(prosledjenaSlika1, image1, options);
  imageLoader.displayImage(prosledjenaSlika2, image2, options);
  imageLoader.displayImage(prosledjenaSlika3, image3, options);
  imageLoader.displayImage(prosledjenaSlika4, image4, options);`

Comment: `prosledjenaSlika1` is String i'm passing from ListView, `image1` is ImageView.

Answer (score 6):

To offer an alternative to Ben's answer and flesh out my earlier comment, one possibility is to create an `ImageView` in your `xml` that occupies the entire screen, with its visibility set to `gone`. On your button press, load the image into this `ImageView`, and on a back press set the visibility to `gone` again.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    >

    <ScrollView>
        <!-- Everything else! -->
    </ScrollView>       

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/full_screen_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Inside your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle mySavedInstances) {
  ImageView fullScreenContainer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_screen_container);

  image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //However it is you load your images
            fullScreenContainer.setImageDrawawble(R.drawable.example);
            fullScreenContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
  });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fullScreenContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        fullScreenContainer.setImageDrawable(null);
        fullScreenContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this onBackPressed method be inside OnClickListener?

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic: No it shouldn't and it isn't.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic Nope. It's a [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed() "onBackPressed()") in the `Activity` class that's called whenever the back key is pressed. You can override it and enter your own logic if you want to customise what happens.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. You both were very helpfull, but because you Ben answered the first and both method works, i'm accepting his answer, but probably i will use answer of PPartisan. :)

Comment: make sure to call `super.onBackPressed()` in `else` at the end. Otherwise normal back behaviour won't work.

Comment: @BugsHappen Good point. Added to my answer. Of course, it also depends on what Dusan wants to happen, but `super.onBackPressed()` needs to be called to finish the `Activity`, as usually happens when using the back key.

Comment: Should  i set scaleType for imageView to FitXY if i want to make ImageView fullscreen?

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic IMO, you should just try the various `ScaleType`s and [see which one works best you](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html "ImageView.ScaleType").

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happens when i click on Image.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic Have you checked to make sure your `NetworkImageView` is responding to click events at all?

Comment: I'm using diffrent class for these images and it is TouchImageView. And no, it is not responding. I have tested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87209/discussion-between-ppartisan-and-dusan-dimitrijevic).

Answer (score 0):

Create new Activity or Fragment and set image to ImageView in new Activity or Fragment. Using Fragment is better approach here as user can click on multiple images one after another. It is less expensive to create or destory Fragment.

Image can be passed to another activity by converting into byte array. It is better approach to save image on server or database such as firebase etc and use generated URL in app. Which make it easy to pass Url between Activities or Fragments than passing byte array